# Is it possible to run an iphonic application in iphone,ipod,ipad and mac?

Tags: objective-c

I want to know whether it is possible to run an iphonic application both in iphone and mac.If it is possible can you guys suggest me how it would be done.

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Sure it's possible. But your question is rather vague. What kind of application. I can have a simple socket client that sends a single packet and I could have code that runs on osx windows the iphone android and linux. But it's not very useful. Please expand if you have a second.

Comment: I would like to run any iphone application in both iphone and mac.If we can run only particular apps in both can u tell what type of apps that we can run on both iphone and mac.

Comment: Well you can run any iPhone app on the simulator. Is that the kind of thing you're talking about?

Comment: Actually one of the interviewer asked me the question how can we run an application in both iphone and mac as we are running the application in iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the option in Xcode to create `Universal` apps. However, this will only cover iDevices. If you wish to compile the same code for MacOS as well you need to do it by inserting preprocessor conditionals

```
#ifdef TARGET_OS_MAC
  // we are on MacOS
#elif defined TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  // we are on iOS
#else
  // unknown platform
#endif
```

That's because the Mac and iOS APIs are at some point different (there are some classes that exclusively exist for each platform, e.g. `UIKit`/`AppKit`)