# What standards and practices should I use to develop an application that runs on both the iPhone and on iPads?

Tags: iphone

What standards and practices should I use to develop an application that runs on both the iPhone and on iPads?

Comment: then how can i find that i need to load xib for iphone or ipad.

Comment: Basically you create one project with two .xib files. One for the iPhone and one for the iPad. At launch you detect the device and load the correct .xib.

Comment: The same is already discussed on SO,
Here is for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387883/is-it-possible-to-run-an-iphonic-application-in-iphone-ipod-ipad-and-mac

Comment: check out this - http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=563 http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf

Comment: That's not a very helpful link as it answers a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, and also on the different iOS versions and hardware versions.

Comment: but how ? because iphone and ipad has different screen size

Comment: Detect the screen size (or platform, whatever) and load the appropriate XIB; or generate the appropriate GUI. And you'll need images in different sizes too.

Comment: Actually you don't need to detect the device to load the xib iOS will automatically load the correct xib for device you just need to create a universal app project.. here you will get separate folder for iPhone and iPad to put your files..

Answer (score 2):

You can build a single app that will run on both iPhone and iPad with ease and Saurabh's Apple link is the best place to start.

You have a couple of things to consider though.

Do you want a universal application that will run on both ipad and iphone or do you want to have separate applications (built from the same project as different targets) for each device?

Some applications are so radically different between iphone and ipad that it makes little sense to try to keep to a single universal application for example. You also need to consider whether you want ipad owners to pay more for a 'HD' version of your app.

Doing RUNTIME detection of which platform you are running on is easy though because Apple have provided the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() macro which returns the appropriate device. This allows you to write code such as this;

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{               
    // Configure for iPad
}
else
{
    // Configure for iPhone
}
```

Typically the configuration code loads the appropriate NIB file if you are using interface builder resources, or alternatively sets up various screen dimension parameters so that the rest of your code scales appropriately.

Note that on iPad you need to support all device orientations, so it's good to factor this in mind right from the start when building for iPhone as well.

There's lots more to learn, but it's all documented over at Apple as usual...